# Volume of solid of revolution of two $x^2+y^2$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate the volume of solid of revolution that enclosed by $x^2+y^2=9$, $x^2+y^2=16$ in quadrant I and revolved around 360-degree about x-axis.

I've tried to put the query of the question in WolframAlpha but the result couldn't be computed.

Could someone help me with the proper integral for the solid of revolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that an integral is not necessary.

Note that the two equations define two concentric circles centered at the origin, the inner one with radius $3$ and the outer one with radius $4$.

The relevant volume of solid of revolution would be the difference in volume between a hemisphere with radius $4$, and a hemisphere with radius $3$.